# html ul li issue in submenu of a phonegap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `li` in my phonegap app like below which has a sub `ul` and `li`

```
<li class="sub-menu "><a href="#">
   <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      Switch City </a>
      <ul class="" id="loadCities">
        <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bangalore</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
       </ul>
</li>
```

Then in the same `ul` I have `li` like below which doesn't have another `ul` and `li` like above.

```
 <li class="no-bullet " onclick="window.location = 'user_profile.html';" >
   <button type="button" class="settings_btn line_height">
     <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
       My Profile</button>
</li>
```

My trouble is I have 2 options where I have sub `ul` and `li` and then I have 4 option where I don't have that structure. And this is causing the height issue, i.e. they are not consistent in size as one becomes button.

What I want is, is there any way that I won't have to use the button under the `li` and on click of the li, I do the redirection to another page which I doing with the help of `onclick="window.location = 'user_profile.html';`

Please suggest a way.

Comment: yes, you can directly use onclick event to li ie `<li class="no-bullet " onclick="window.location = 'user_profile.html';" ></li>` ,you don't have to write button inside li

Comment: or else you can use this code            `<li class="no-bullet "><a class="settings_btn line_height" href="#" onclick="location.href = 'user_profile.html'">My Profile</a></li>`